# Quest item has been pushed through a wall

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm currently playing through the [Tending the Flames](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Tending_the_Flames) quest.  I have reached the point where I'm in the room where Svaknir's body and soul are located, and the book should be, but it wasn't there.

I tried the [console command](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) `tfc` to go and look through the walls, and I saw the book had somehow dropped just below the floor.

Without replaying the whole tomb from the start, is there a way to just move that item using a console command to a place above the ground where I can take it?  Or to just move it to my inventory?  I want a risk free way of doing it, up to now my game hasn't had a single bug!

Cheers

Comment: This game has entirely too many game breaking bugs.

Comment: @Ender I agree. However, the team behind the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1214251-wipannounce-unofficial-skyrim-patch/) is working on it. (Can't really count on Bethesda.)

Comment: If you haven't already, email them... http://support.bethsoft.com/eng/email.asp  and link them to this.  It might help, it might not but this game has been out for 4 months now and this is getting ridiculous.  I almost feel like there should be a petition for this.

Comment: Just FYI, Bethesda seems to have fixed this in [the latest patch](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/news/article.php?id=87) (currently in beta).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use the `tcl` command to toggle clipping on your character.  Go under the floor where the item fell and pick it up.  Once you have it, return above the ground and enter `tcl` again, which will re-enable clipping.

Comment: its amazing with this game that we have to 'cheat' to really beat it legit, I've had to resort to this too on a couple items that just 'dropped out'

Answer (score 3):

For those on an XBOX or PS3, the [same wiki page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Tending_the_Flames) where you reference the quest actually has other suggestions for getting the verse back:

> Using the Dawnbreaker anywhere in the dungeon and causing a corpse
>   explosion effect triggers a bug that clips the verse into the floor,
>   making it irretrievable and breaking the quest. When this bug appears
>   simply walk back then kill the two undead with the Dawnbraker, return
>   and the verse should be visible. Alternatively, use a fireball (or any
>   other explosives) to "shake up things" and verse will fall out of the
>   rock.
>
> The verse is stuck underneath the ground. Using "tcl" (noclip)
>   in console will let you dive under the surface to pick it up. Just be
>   sure to turn noclip back on when you're on solid ground again.

Answer (score 0):

The [version 1.5.24.0 patch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Version_1.5.24.0) seems to now have fixed this:

> In [Tending the Flames](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Tending_the_Flames), [King Olaf's Verse](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:King_Olaf%27s_Verse) will no longer disappear from explosions.

If it's still missing despite having the latest patch installed, just 'teleport' King Olaf's Verse (the book) to you by using the console commands:

`prid AE324`
`moveto player`

Alternatively, you could also add it to your inventory using the ff: console command:

`player.additem AE324 1`

More info on console commands at [UESP wiki's '**Console**' article](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console).