# Nettlebane lost due to clipping bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just killed the hagraven at Orphan's Rock after a hairy fight. Now I can't loot Nettlebane because when she died she clipped through the ground and her body disappeared. Is there any solution to this? Can you summon an item by console command?

Comment: Related (but I think not quite a duplicate because it tends to only work inside where items are less likely to fall out of the world): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53324/quest-item-has-been-pushed-through-a-wall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `additem 0001c492`, or use `tcl` to clip through the ground yourself to retrieve it if it hasn't fallen out of the world.

Comment: Thanks. Had a laugh when I traveled to the Stormcloak camp nearby and found her there.